# Get copy of Google Cache for PDF that is no longer live

Tags: pdf, caching, search, archive

I am looking for some specific information about an obscure church.  This PDF keeps popping up in Google but the link goes to a site that is no longer live.

This is the link that comes up:
https://www.firstcontact.website/introduction-to-site.pdf

I can get the search result from several different search strings and each time it will show different preview text.  Google must have a cache of this PDF.

There is no "cached" option to click.  Many pages have that green arrow if the cache is available.

I have tried searching the Google cache like this:
cache:www.firstcontact.website/introduction-to-site.pdf
or 
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:%3Cwww.firstcontact.website/introduction-to-site.pdf%3E

No luck.  I know Google has a cached version and I would very much like to read it.  Any idea on how I can access this document?

Here is a screenshot of the Google Search result:

[image: Google search result]

Comment: not sure if it helps you, but poking around with the domain got me redirected to https://spiritdwelling.com/ - there is a contact page, maybe you could email them and ask for the document, looks like it's the same or related website

Comment: As resourceful as the answer is, this question is not about programming, and is thus not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Don't forget to copy the below text, in case it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my best effort to extract the cached content.

**Metadata:**

**Bing:** "introduction-to-site.pdf"

> **Title:** Microsoft Word - Introduction to Site
>
> **Author:** BrianKipp
>
> **Created Date:** 11/14/2018 5:38:39 PM

**Content:**

**Google (repeatedly):** site:www.firstcontact.website *"small chunk of content from cache"*

> Introduction and Purpose
>
> There is a small white church on the south side of the Thompson River,
>   at the base of a large slide. For fifty years I passed by that church.
>   Five years ago I made an impulsive decision to find a way to the other
>   side of the river to make photographs of the place. Near an unmarked
>   road which I speculated led to the church, I met a First Nations man
>   who confirmed it was the way. He also told me there was another
>   beautiful church on the road to. Merritt (Shackan) that his auntie
>   cares for, which I found and photographed months later. The road was
>   rutted and rocky, with treacherous drop-offs; a suitable foreshadowing
>   of my journey over the five years to come. Until that moment my small
>   Mercedes had not realized it was an off-road vehicle! The church was
>   St. Aidan's Anglican on what was formerly the land of the Pokhaist
>   people, right below their sacred “White Rock”. First I photographed
>   the exterior, then through the windows, the interior. The front door
>   was held only by a wire latch, stepping inside I was in awe at the
>   humility of this spiritual place. Five rows of grey hand-crafted pews,
>   sitting on a floor of rough planks. At the front of the church, to the
>   left, stood a wood stove with a stack of dried wood, ready for the
>   next service. There was a high-back bishop's chair with very short
>   legs near the stove. In front of the altar there was a very simple
>   box, not unlike a fruit-box on its side, with a
>
> Page 2.
>
> kneeling platform. It was a crude pre-dieu, where congregants and
>   priest could kneel to pray. The plain wooden altar was backed by a
>   dossal curtain, and above that a weathered picture of the Last Supper.
>   St. Aidan's was built around 1890 by the Pokhaist people, in the hopes
>   of attracting a priest to visit their village.  Their choice of
>   location is evidence of syncretism, the fusion of diverse religious
>   beliefs and practices. They chose to place the church directly below
>   White Stone, a traditional sacred place where the shamans prayed and
>   young men went as part of their coming of age ceremony. I imagined the
>   small group of people gathered here in quiet worship. I imagined
>   wedding ceremonies, funerals and baptisms in this building on the
>   river, and the sun-weathered face of the priest who had ridden 50
>   kilometres on horseback from his base in Lytton. The images were so
>   strong that they became memories, not of what I had seen, but of what
>   has been. St. Aidan's inspired me to see more. I began to travel
>   throughout the province looking for every. First Nations church still
>   standing. I met with the Anglican Bishop Barbara Andrews and Catholic.
>   Bishop David Munroe in Kamloops. After seeing my images Bishop
>   Andrews, herself First. Nations, commented “I can see that you are on
>   a spiritual journey." That is what my project had become. In most
>   villages, I had the opportunity to talk to some of the inhabitants.
>   They would say things like “my parents were married in that church” or
>   “we lived in this beautiful place, for centuries, then the white men
>   came to build a railway and decided they would stay and take our
>   land." They would also tell me where I could find other churches,
>   which kept the journey alive. In discussing spirituality, one elder
>   told me that their traditional spiritual practices and moral code were
>   well aligned with Christianity, as both practices were based on the
>   belief of a Great. Creator. To this day, the peoples in his nation
>   embrace Christianity as part of their daily life. He said that their
>   old ways also included a belief in reincarnation. I asked if he had
>   been reincarnated, and he said “I have had two lives, and I hope that
>   the good Lord will give me one more so that I can finish my work
>   here." He also said that the one part of Christianity he “could never
>   accept was that a loving God would create a lake of fire to punish
>   sinners to eternity." Talking to an elder in a coffee shop in the Nass
>   Valley, I had the opportunity to get a glimpse into the aboriginals'
>   connection with the land and nature. I asked him the significance of
>   an encounter I had with an owl. The owl had flown beside my car for 50
>   metres, looking in my window, before it flew in front of the car and
>   into the nearby trees. He said “Was it a large or small owl?” I told
>   him it was large. “That's good, because a small owl would mean a
>   death. The large owl meant to tell you that you are on the right path,
>   and you should continue.” He seemed very certain of his statement, and
>   the other elders present agreed with his interpretation. As I made my
>   way through this journey, questions naturally emerged. What motivated
>   the. Christian conversion of First Nations people? Why did the priests
>   show no curiosity or respect for
>
> Page 3.
>
> traditional belief systems? What was the moral and legal basis for the
>   pre-empting of First. Nations lands? How did the locals respond to the
>   theft of their land? How and why did they create Indian Residential
>   Schools? Searching for answers to these and other questions, I
>   acquired every book I could find on the topic. New questions arose.
>   How did the objectives and methods of the various denominations
>   differ? Where did these migrant priests come from? What was the
>   relationship between church and state in BC? How did Christianity
>   compare to traditional aboriginal beliefs? By answering these and
>   other questions that arose on my travels, I began to understand the
>   story of our First. Nations encounter with British colonization. My
>   early photographs of the churches presented the buildings as beautiful
>   architectural objects, infused with a sense of spirituality. At some
>   point, I realized that the spirituality is bound to the land, as is
>   the history of the aboriginal people. The buildings could not stand
>   alone without showing their place. I returned to many of the churches
>   and photographed them “in their place."  Locating these old churches
>   was time consuming. Documentation was scarce and many of the churches
>   have disappeared through weathering or vandalism. Many of the churches
>   are no longer used for services, so only the elders have memories to
>   share. Several of my trips were fruitless confirmations that some
>   churches no longer exist. Discovery of the Leon Creek church came
>   through a chance encounter with a woman in Sechelt, who described a
>   church in Pemberton that her son had photographed. She promised to
>   send me his photos, and a week later they arrived by post. Looking at
>   the images, I surmised the geography was clearly not Pemberton, more
>   likely Lillooet. I took the photos to the Lillooet. Museum, where they
>   confirmed it was the “Galvanized Church” up West Pavilion Road, no
>   directions beyond that. Sixty kilometres up the dirt road I came upon
>   two trucks blocking the path. Two men and a woman, in the middle of a
>   tailgate party, advised me that I had passed the church road 15
>   kilometres earlier. The woman looked at my car and The woman looked at
>   my car and said “You're not going in there in that!" Was she ever
>   right! I went back to Vancouver to get a 4X4 and try again. Even then,
>   the road was a nail-biter, lots of drops of 500 feet or more, and
>   narrow sections where the inside wheel had to be up on the bank to
>   keep the truck on the road. A year later, I met a man who had been
>   raised in a log cabin beside the church. He still cares for the
>   church, stating “I am not religious, but my grandmother was. I
>   maintain the church building now out of respect for her memory." A
>   remarkable set of connections leading me to a most spectacular scene.
>   A young man in Sardis told me about the church at Kanaka Bar. Driving
>   down a narrow dirt road,. I was unable to find the church where I had
>   been told it would be.  Eventually, my wheels spun in loose gravel and
>   with disappointment I turned around. Retracing my steps, the church
>   showed itself 20 feet above the road, encircled by tall trees.
>   Entering through the open doorway, I heard
>
> Page 4.
>
> a buzzing noise to my left. There was a hummingbird flying against the
>   window, weakened by its efforts. I cupped the tiny bird in my hands
>   and released it outside. It was an amazing moment for me, a spiritual
>   connection with the place. Another chance connection occurred in
>   Quilchena, while looking for a church long gone. I went into the
>   Quilchena General Store for assistance. Although they were unaware of
>   the old. Quilchena church, they advised me to get the book, Archdeacon
>   on Horseback.  They phoned ahead to a Merritt bookstore, the staff
>   arranged for the author Murphy Shewchuk, to meet me with a copy of his
>   book.  It told the story of a young priest, Richard Small, who covered
>   the area from Lytton to Merritt on horseback. By following the route
>   of his travels, I was able to find additional churches.  In all, I
>   spent five years traveling around BC, making photographs of these
>   amazing buildings. I feel very fortunate to have captured images of so
>   many of them, as the buildings are deteriorating each time I visit
>   them.
>
> The Churches.
>
> The early churches were humble buildings made from locally milled
>   wood, all constructed by aboriginal craftsmen. In some cases the
>   churches were much more elaborate, and the locals labored up to 10
>   years building them. The Church of the Holy Cross in Skatin is now a
>   National. Heritage Site, showcasing native craftsmanship and
>   commitment. The greatest architectural challenge was usually the
>   steeple. Sometimes a simple steeple housing the bell was attached to
>   the roof line. In most cases, the steeple was a separate structure
>   that was attached to the front of the church building. Toppling of
>   both types of bell towers was a problem, and aboriginal craftsmen
>   tried numerous ingenious solutions. As illustration, the steeple at
>   Spaxomin church still stands held up by external braces at its base to
>   keep it from falling sideways. Not successful was the rooftop steeple
>   on the Cayuse Creek church, which has fallen off entirely. The Tahltan
>   church building has separated from the steeple, and only the steeple
>   stands today. The churches included in this book are the remaining
>   physical evidence of colonialism and the early spread of Christianity
>   to our First Nations. They are fast disappearing. In 18 Mile village a
>   woman who lived up the hill from the church said it all: “I pass the
>   church every day, I just cannot imagine it not being there."
>
> Page 5.
>
> Historical Context.
>
> James Douglas founded Fort Victoria in 1843 on behalf of the Hudson's
>   Bay Company. His ties to the church went back to his days in Fort St.
>   James, and when he explored the regions of. Vancouver Island he took
>   the priest Jean-Baptist Bolduc with him to convert the local natives
>   to. Christianity. When the Gold Rush began in 1858, Douglas left the
>   company and became the first governor of the province of BC. He acted
>   quickly to establish British laws throughout the territory and to
>   assert ownership of the colony. The miners' behaviour was unbridled by
>   rules, or respect for the places and people they encountered. The
>   first consequence was felt by the First Nations people.  Their wives
>   were taken by the miners, men and women alike were poisoned by the
>   alcohol they introduced, and diseases such as smallpox ravaged the
>   First Nations people. Over 40 percent of the miners coming to BC were
>   Americans. Concerned that their numbers posed a threat to the
>   sovereignty of British Columbia, Douglas organized “bride-ships”
>   filled with young English women for the purpose of marrying settlers
>   and establishing traditional British families. My great-grandfather,
>   Henry Kipp, was settled in Chilliwack with a First Nations wife and a
>   child. When the bride-ships came to Victoria, Henry Kipp took a
>   British bride. His aboriginal wife and daughter were relocated across
>   the river in Mission, where his daughter attended school at St. Mary's
>   Convent. In an effort to establish a civil society (ie. British) the
>   government decided that separating the. First Nations people from the
>   settlers was desirable. The churches were effective organizations to
>   undertake this division of society. The churches took measures to
>   physically isolate the aboriginals from the settlers. They encouraged
>   temperance amongst First Nations, they insisted on a monogamist
>   lifestyle (even though the locals had practiced a form of polygamy in
>   many cases) and the First Nations people were relocated geographically
>   in “reductions” away from the town centers. One elder that I spoke to
>   in the Fraser Valley made this comment: “They built the church, and
>   told us we should all move closer so that we would be closer to God;
>   then they built a fence around us and stole our land."
>
> Culture Clash.
>
> It was the European view that existing First Nations spiritual
>   practices, deemed meaningless mythology and superstition, stood in the
>   way of Christian conversion. Cultural practices such as potlatch,
>   polygamy and native languages were specifically targeted as
>   impediments to conversion. The Roman Catholic church developed the
>   Durieu Method to eliminate these. "distractions." They forbade
>   speaking native languages or practicing cultural traditions. A network
>   of monitors was established in each village, and offenders were
>   punished by public humiliation. The Anglicans, too, used public
>   shaming as a means of encouraging compliance with their expectations.
>   Once a year the bishop would travel to Lytton to induct new members
>   into the
>
> Page 6.
>
> church. In front of hundreds of their peers, each candidate had to
>   answer questions posed by the bishop. If they failed to answer
>   correctly, they were told to think about the questions, and then face
>   the bishop's questions again. In these same meetings, members of the
>   village who had transgressed church rules in the past year were
>   publicly identified.
>
> Residential Schools.
>
> In 1876 Sir John A. MacDonald's federal government implemented the
>   Indian Act which made it federal responsibility to educate First
>   Nations children. The churches played a key role in the education
>   strategy, which was to establish residential schools to teach the
>   native children. English, convert them to Christianity and make them
>   Euro-Canadians. It is not widely known that up until the late 1950's
>   these schools were half-day only, and the students were required to
>   work half-days to contribute to the costs of running the schools.
>   Until the 1960's, children were not allowed to return home for
>   holidays. Children were removed from their families and relocated to
>   distant boarding schools, where they were victims of systematic
>   destruction of their language and culture. In addition to the
>   traumatic uprooting from their homes, these children suffered all
>   forms of abuse, including pedophilia. The trauma of having their
>   children taken overwhelmed native villagers with grief and loss. The
>   Truth and Reconciliation process gave First Nations people the chance
>   to be heard, through interviews with the Truth and Reconciliation
>   Commission. The commission produced its report in. 2016, and today
>   dialogue continues. It may take generations for our First Nations
>   people to recover from this relatively recent history.
>
> Land Claims.
>
> The government dispatched surveyors to mark out plots of land,
>   including First Nations reserves. The government issued deeds to
>   surveyed lands for settlers, with no regard to First Nations claims to
>   the land. There is a photo in the University of British Columbia
>   archives showing.  Governor Frederick Seymour meeting with the people
>   of Lillooet in 1865, to discuss land claims which were never resolved.
>   When the gold rush ended in the Cariboo, the miners often returned to
>   claim land in the regions that they had passed through. One of the
>   elders that I spoke to described the idyllic locale on the small
>   isthmus of Seton Portage. “We grew fruit and vegetables, and sold them
>   to neighboring bands throughout the area. It was a good life. When the
>   railway workers came through, they claimed our land, paying no heed to
>   the fact that we had farmed here for generations.”

Comment: I gave you the bounty.  Nice work!  So you repeatedly googled the document and eventually pieced this together from the preview snippet?

That did the trick!  I was hoping to learn how to access the actual cached content directly but thanks a lot for digging up this info.